# How can I send fetched data to my ViewController?

Tags: swift, parsing, fetch-api, pokeapi

Heres a caption of my API call:
[image]

So, I've got the abilities of the pokemons I needed, but now, idk how to get that data out of my Service class (where I'm doing all the parsing), and send it to my InfoViewController.

My purpose is to fetch that data on some label, and then show the ability names for every poke, according to their ID. Here is a caption of my app:
[image]

I wanna add an "Ability" label below Weight, and that's where I wanna assign the data. I have a whole CollectionView with all the pokemons, and the goal is assign the correct ability for each one of them.

I'm kinda struggling for a practical (and less verbose) way to reach this.

I apreciated every comment, any advice and suggestion too. Thanks!

EDIT: Heres my code:

```
extension InfoController: ServiceDelegate {
        
    func finishedWithPokemonAbilities(abilities: [String], id: Int) {
        
        self.abilities = abilities
        self.ids = id
        
        print(abilities)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't show pictures of code, please. Code is text. Copy and paste your code into the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `Protocol`(could call it `PokemonServiceDelegate` as an example)  that your `InfoViewController` would inherit and implement.  On your service object(I'm using `PokemonService` in the example) create a property with a type of `PokemonServiceDelegate` and set that property to the view controller that you want to receive the data.  After the service finishes fetching the data, update the delegate by passing the data in the function declared in the protocol.

```
// Protocol your view controller will inherit
protocol PokemonServiceDelegate {
    // Function your view controller will implement
    func finishedWithPokemonAbilities(abilities: [String])
}

class InfoViewController: UIViewController {
    // Reference to the service that makes the request
    var service: PokemonService
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        // Set the delegate of the service to self
        service.delegate = self
        ...
    }
}

extension InfoViewController: PokemonServiceDelegate {
    // Implement the protocol
    func finishedWithPokemonAbilities(abilities: [String]) {
        // Do something with their abilities here
    }
}

struct PokemonService {
    var delegate: PokemonServiceDelegate?
    // The function that you call to get your abilities
    func someUpdateFunc() {
        ...
            let abilities = json[abilities].arrayValue.map {$0["ability"]["name"].stringValue}

            delegate?.finishedWithPokemonAbilities(abilities: abilities)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Now when I print the data to check if I got it, it doesn't return anything on the console. Why would that be for? I updated my post with some code.

Comment: Are you calling `delegate?.finishedWithPokemonAbilities(abilities: abilities)` from your service object?